# input-prepend create two rows

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add two buttons on both sides of the search field, so I did this:

```
<div id="fixtures-filter">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <div class="input-group-prepend"><button type="button" class="btn btn-light" aria-expanded="false" id="countries-btn">Filters</button></div>
    <div class="app-search">
      <div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."><span class="mdi mdi-magnify"></span>
        <div class="input-group-append"><button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fixtures-filter-modal">Search</button> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the result is really weird:

[image]

[This is a JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rp51o4se/67/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get the filter to be on the same line, you have to move it inside the same parent div as the other inputs:

```
<div id="fixtures-filter">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <div class="app-search">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" aria-expanded="false" id="countries-btn"><span class="mdi mdi-magnify"></span></button></div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control padleft" placeholder="Search...">
        <span class="mdi mdi-magnify search-mg"></span>
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fixtures-filter-modal">Search</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS added to get the magnifying glass icon to appear in the search input:

```
#fixtures-filter {
  position: relative;
}
span.search-mg {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 38px;
    left: 45px;
}

.padleft {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5xkbn3o0/

Comment: ok, but if you look at this update: http://jsfiddle.net/rp51o4se/73/ you can see that the icon inside the span overlay the button in the prepend, why?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the magnifying glass?

Comment: I moved the magnifying glass inside the button. Not sure if that is what you want to do.

Comment: Nope, I mean the magnifying glass on the left, this should be on the input not on the button

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want this to look like? An image or a working example on another site would help.

Comment: take a look at this search bar: https://coderthemes.com/hyper/index.html the code is the same

Comment: The icon is absolutely positioned in that example, and they added left padding to the input to make room for it.

Comment: @PUNGIS Please clarify what you're trying to do as the answer already explains how to prepend a button the the input.

Comment: @Dylan I simply need to achieve the same result, add the icon inside the text input with the layout that you gave to me

Answer (score 1):

Use an append and prepend. Adjust the borders as needed to make the search icon appear inside the input.

```
   <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-prepend">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                        Filters
                    </button>
              </span>
              <span class="input-group-prepend">
                    <div class="input-group-text bg-transparent border-right-0"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
              </span>
              <input class="form-control py-2 border-left-0 border" type="search" value="..." id="example-search-input">
              <span class="input-group-append">
                   <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary border-left-0 border" type="button">
                       Search
                   </button>
              </span>
   </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/KJcZWvSsR9

Comment: I appreciate the effort but the icon must be inside the text input as displayed here: https://coderthemes.com/hyper/index.html

Comment: "the icon must be inside the text input as displayed here".. no, the icon is not inside the input on coderthemes, it only appears inside the input, just like the example I created